# Plain text with embedded html tags are not rendering properly

Tags: python, html, django

I have a 'blog' page on my website where I submit blog entries with embedded HTML tags and would like the entires to then render those tags properly.
An example entry:

```
<p>Blog Blog Blog!</p>
```

But, when I display these entries on my webpage the tags turn into their plaintext equivalents:

```
&lt;p&gt;
Blog Blog Blog
&lt;/p&gt;
```

Thus, the HTML tags are no more and the page is just rendering as `<p>Blog Blog Blog </p>`

Is there something I can do to have all my tags render properly? (Javascript?) I'm using Django models to store my blog entries and the template system to then show the entries on my page. Code:

**models.py**

`class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    content = models.TextField()
    picture = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title`

**blog.html**

`{% for b in blogs %}
    {% if b.picture %}
        <img class="pic" src="{% static 'img/{{ b.picture }}' %}">
    {% endif %}
    <h2>{{ b.title }}</h2>
    <h4>{{ b.subtitle }}</h4>
    <p>{{ b.date }}</p>
    <div id="content">
        {{ b.content }}
    </div>
    {% for t in b.tags.objects.all %}
        {{ t.subject }} 
    {% endfor %}
        <hr>
{% endfor %}`

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried applying the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) template tag?

Comment: Wow. I figured there would be an easy way to do this, but I wasn't expecting a 5 character fix. Thanks a ton!